# Switch position of divs in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to switch positions of div when i click on the header. Here is my HTML sample:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
<p>Paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
<p>Paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
<p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

And this is my jquery:

```
$(".header-wrapper h3").click( function() { $(".main-wrapper").prependTo(".header-wrapper:first"); });
```

the problem is that right now it tries to put all the .main-wrappers before the first but i want only the one that holds the h3 i've clicked on

Answer (score 3):

You should embeded all your main-wrapper elements in a container (or use body):

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b4dyM/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
     <h3>Header</h3>

  </div>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
</div>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
     <h3>Header</h3>

  </div>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
     <h3>Header</h3>

  </div>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>

  </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".header-wrapper h3").click(function () {
  var $mainrWrap = $(this).closest(".main-wrapper");
  $(this).closest(".container").prepend($mainrWrap);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It really isnt clear what you are trying to do but you can get the `.main-wrapper` that you clicked in with `$(this).parent().parent()`.

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/c2U3g/2/

```
$(".header-wrapper h3").click(function () {
 if (!$(this).closest(".main-wrapper").is(":first-child")) {
  $(this).closest(".main-wrapper").insertBefore(".main-wrapper:first");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".main-wrapper")
```

abovle line actually selects all of divs with main-wrapper class. Inside event callback function *this* refers to clicked element (basically target of the event).

[jsfiddle demo solving the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/uUNcP/)

```
var firstWrapper = $(".main-wrapper").first(),
    clickedWrapper = $(this).parents(".main-wrapper");

if (!clickedWrapper.is(":first-child")) {
    clickedWrapper.insertBefore(firstWrapper)
}
```

I split the code a little bit more than you would usually do; What happens is:

1. firstWrapper variable holds reference to first of all div with main-wrapper class
2. clickedWrapper: using parents(".main-wrapper") to look up ancerstor tree to find an ancestor element with main-wrapper class
3. If instruction checks whether clickedWrapper isn't the first one. We do nothing when it is. If it's not, we insert clickedWrapper before firstWrapper.